# Parse SDK gives: "Error: pointer field owner needs a pointer value" on Facebook login

Tags: parse-platform

Ok this error broke our live app and we have no idea of what it is. After a users logs in with Facebook we get this error: `Error: pointer field owner needs a pointer value`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen to all users or some of?

Comment: [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828732/parse-com-query-on-pointer-value) This could be the reason. You can update the way your app handles Parse.com api

Answer (score 8):

When I had this error, it was because I was passing a string instead of an object of the type that I had a pointer to. Try passing the actual object.

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing any code it sounds like you are trying to access the owner field by passing a string instead of explicitly stating and id.

Incorrect:

```
[query whereKey:@"post"
        equalTo:@"1zEcyElZ80"];
```

Correct:

```
[query whereKey:@"post"
        equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Post" objectId:@"1zEcyElZ80"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are parsing STRING, where as it needs to be parsed as a Pointer. Here's a PHP example:

```
$userId = "123456";

$query = ParseUser::query();
$query->equalTo("objectId", array("__type" => "Pointer", "className" => "_User", "objectId" => $userId));
$result = $query->find();

print_r($result);
```

It will spit out all the information of the user. I'm sure you can handle the rest. If you are having an issue with iOS, its similar issue just change the syntax.